# Help with this query, joining three tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

Can you help me with this query:
I have three tables

first, main table

```
page_id | title
1 aaa
2 bbb
3 ccc
4 ddd
```

revision tbl:

```
id | rev_page | rev_text_id
1 1 1 
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 3 5
6 3 6
7 4 7
```

text table:

```
old_id | old_text
1 some_text_blob
2 some_text_blob
3 some_text_blob
4 some_text_blob
5 some_text_blob
6 some_text_blob
7 some_text_blob
```

I used this query

```
SELECT c.old_id,c.old_text 
FROM text c 
INNER JOIN revision b ON c.old_id=b.rev_text_id 
INNER JOIN page a ON a.page_id=b.rev_page 
WHERE a.page_id=3
```

and I get

```
3 some_text_blob
5 some_text_blob
6 some_text_blob
```

I need only the last one, 
`6 some_text_blob`.

Comment: Last one based on what? ID column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order resulting table in the reverse chronological order and limit result to single row:

```
SELECT c.old_id,c.old_text 
  FROM text     AS c 
  JOIN revision AS b ON c.old_id=b.rev_text_id 
  JOIN page     AS a ON a.page_id=b.rev_page 
 WHERE a.page_id=3
 ORDER BY b.rev_text_id DESC
 LIMIT 1
;
```